# Helpme with own functions in api-platform

Tags: api-platform.com

recently I have been working with symfony 4 in search of some solution for the creation of web services api-rest and I have found api-platform. After several days trying, because I do not have much knowledge of symfony, I managed to raise the API for an entity that I created by default. It turns out that now I have the doubt of how to add to the api methods other than those that are by default, say the put, the get and others that are already by default, I want to be able to add to my entity the methods that I estimate necessary and with the name that I want. Please I would appreciate your help with some form or some simple steps that allow me to add new methods to the api always keeping in mind that I do not have much knowledge in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to avoid endpoint proliferation as much as possible, [think REST](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9)
2. the recommended way to hook your own logic in API Platform is using [the built-in events](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#the-event-system)
3. if you really need to add custom endpoints, [here is a dedicated documentation entry](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers), but it should be your last resort (see 1/)